# Extremely long IO WAIT reported for PHP accessing Redis

Tags: php, redis, blackfire

As attached, Blackfire is reporting that all Redis actions have ridiculous latency with the Redis hosted on the same container. The hypervisor is not reporting high IO wait. The redis does not contain many keys but it is frequently accessed. How can this be happening? I've checked `ulimit` and the daemon files and increased the TCP port range. Just clueless what this is.

[image: Long Redis IO Wait]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of tinkering, I have come to the conclusion the issue was the hypervisor.

I moved Redis out to the host (I was using Proxmox 6.4-13) and set the connection to the local network IP. The issues instantly resolved.